# linking prebuild lib for every instruction set NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries

EDIT: I would like to linking prebuild lib, but i dont know how to call this fftw3.libs from obj...folder, for every instructions sets: I have to use if condtioiton for every ?

```
          LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
      include $(CLEAR_VARS)

          LOCAL_MODULE    := fftw3_mod
       LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= libfftw3_mod.a

     include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)



  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
      LOCAL_MODULE    := com_jp_algi_CoreC
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := After.cpp com_jp_algi_CoreC.cpp FFTReal.cpp



      LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /FileBroswer/jni/Eigen 
      ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
        LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp 
        LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true


      endif 
     include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach is to puf the prebuilt libs in subfolders `armeabi`, `x86`, etc.

```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
  include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := fftw3_mod
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfftw3_mod.a

 include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfftw3_mod.aI use a nd says:The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item

Comment: Where did `LOCAL_LDLIBS` come from?

Comment: Check that jni/jni/libs/armeabi/libfftw3_mod.a exists  or that its path is correct

Comment: i COPY THE THARGET_ABI INTO JNI FOlDER but i Donkt knowif its ok:) but it runs ok